# PHP - Creating array list

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create array which will look like this:

```
Array (
    1 => Array(
        2 => Array (
            3 => Array ()
        )
    )
)
```

this array should be generated from array which looks like this:

```
Array (
    1,
    2,
    3
)
```

I am not really sure how to better describe this in words, so thats why I show you this example. 3 values is only for purpose of this example, in real script number of values is vary. Thanks for any advice.

---

**Solved**, thanks for marking as duplicated. In case somebody will have same question as me, here is solution.

```
function setArrayValue(&$array, $path, $value) {
    $temp = &$array;

    foreach($path as $key)
        $temp =& $temp[$key];

    $temp = $value;
}

$keys = Array(
    10,
    9,
    8,
    7,
    6,
    5,
    4,
    3,
    2,
    1
);

$keys   = array_reverse($keys);
$array  = Array();
$path   = Array();

foreach ($keys AS $i => $key) {
    $path[] = $key;

    if (array_key_exists(++$i, $keys))
        $value = Array(
            $keys[$i] => Array(),
        );
    else
        $value = Array();

    if ($i == 0) {
        $array[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        setArrayValue($array, $path, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a recursive function?

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver, I already make it works as required.